# Error build with netbeans 7.3, use JDK1.7.0_79 and eclipselink

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, netbeans

im newbie for java programming.. i want to ask when i build with netbeans and use JPA for library.. show this error.. i try to change eclipse link in module netbeans with from version 1.0 to 2.5.. or maybe my jdk must be change..?? i dont know..

> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
>    Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
>   Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
>   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
>   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
>   Note: Found Option : eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory, with value: false
>   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
>   Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
>   warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   1 warning
>   Copying 30 files to C:\Users\Damkar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APDN_DAO\build\classes
>   compile:
>   Created dir: C:\Users\Damkar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APDN_DAO\dist
>   Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Damkar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APDN_DAO\build
>   C:\Users\Damkar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APDN_DAO\nbproject\build-impl.xml:993: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Damkar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APDN_DAO\nbproject\build-impl.xml:837: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

can u help me about this guys..

Comment: This is not an error, it's a warning, as it says as very first word.

Comment: but i cant build my program...

Comment: Then read this part of the message above, it's the only relevant part, actually: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Users\Damkar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\APDN_DAO\nbproject\build-impl.xml:837: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute BUILD FAILED (total time: